# What happens when a class is set by reference

Tags: c++

I'm moving from using the C-style of setting values for structs in functions via ptrs to C++ style of using object references. What I don't understand is, when I pass an object by reference, and then set it to a new object, how is the data set? I would have thought it was the copy constructor, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Example

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Profile{
    public:
  string name;
  int age;
  Profile();
  ~Profile();
  Profile( const Profile &profile); 
};
Profile::Profile(){
    name = "BILLY BOB";
    age = 234;
}
Profile::~Profile(){}
Profile::Profile( const Profile &profile){
    cout << "COPY CONSTRUCTOR" << endl;
}

void GetProfile(Profile &profile){
    cout << &profile << endl;
    Profile p;
    // what's going on here?
    profile = p; 
}

int main()
{
    Profile p;
    p.name = "MIKE";
    p.age = 55;
    cout << p.name << endl;
    cout << p.age << endl;
    cout << &p << endl;
    GetProfile(p);
    cout << p.name << endl;
    cout << p.age << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Everything is set properly, I just don't understand how.

Comment: Note that this is about assignment vs construction and references are just distracting from the real issue.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Not sure what you mean about "distracting from the real issue"

Comment: In your GetProfile() function you are settings the contents of the reference parameter to a newly created Profile object. This will not contain the values that you set in the main() function.

Comment: I mean that you don't need references to replicate the problem you are asking about.

Comment: offtopic (but on topic)  age = age/3; in your copy constructor is UB since age hasn't been assigned a value yet.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I still don't know what you mean - I don't have any problems, ie bugs, just wasn't sure what was happening, and the answer is that it's the Copy Assignment, not Copy Constructor, that gets called.

Comment: @UKMonkey true, removed.

Comment: @peer_2_peer_2 Yes, but if you read what you wrote you'll notice that the question is centered around references. But references don't cause what you are asking about.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Please elaborate, if you can.

Comment: @peer_2_peer_2 I mean, I don't know how to elaborate. The difference between copy construction and copy assignment just doesn't require that the object be referred to by a reference to be observed. Maybe an example : https://godbolt.org/z/q5Ke99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment is happening.
Try adding:

```
class Profile{
    public:
  string name;
  int age;
  Profile();
  ~Profile();
  Profile( const Profile &profile); 
  Profile &operator = (const Profile &);
};
Profile &Profile::operator = ( const Profile &profile){
    cout << "COPY ASSIGNMENT" << endl;
    age = age/3;
    return *this;
}
```

You wrote `profile = p;`. `profile` is a variable, to which some value will be assigned. In that case `operator =` will be executed on this variable, so class user could modify, how class values are assigned. You're free (as class writer) to do, whatever you want in this assignment operator. You don't have to do the same, as in copy constructor (although you should, as users will be suprised). And you don't even have to return `*this`, although once again if you dont, then your users will be suprised.

EDIT:
in c++11 and future there's also move constructor / assignment:

```
class Profile{
    public:
  string name;
  int age;
  Profile();
  ~Profile();
  Profile( const Profile &profile); 
  Profile( Profile &&profile); 
  Profile &operator = (const Profile &);
  Profile &operator = (Profile &&);
};
Profile &Profile::operator = ( Profile &&profile){
    cout << "COPY ASSIGNMENT" << endl;
    age = age/3;
    return *this;
}
```

those are going to be "fired", when you will assign (or create) **from** temporary variable. For example:

```
Profile p;
p = Profile(...);
```

in a second line you get temporary `Profile` value, which move assignment hopefully might somehow utilize, since that value is going to be destroyed anyway. So for example strings will pass it's content instead of copying, and so on.

Comment: Oh I see - I just looked at the rule of 3 again - i thought it was Constructor/Destructor/Copy Constructor, but it's actually Destructor/Copy Constructor/Copy Assignment

Comment: Yes. Also in "newer" C++  the rule is now named rule of 5 - you get move constructor and move assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to start by stating that the copy constructor is incorrect: The variables are not being initialized, therefore, it will not work the way you think it will work:

You should fix it, like this:

```
Profile::Profile(const Profile &profile)
: name(profile.name) // copy name
, age(profile.age) // copy age
{
    cout << "COPY CONSTRUCTOR" << endl;
    age = age/3; // this variable was used without being initialized
}
```

Now, to the issue:

The variable `profile` is already initialized, it will not be created again! When you use the assignment operator, the compiler will call, well, `the assignment operator`!

If an implementation is not provided, the compiler will generate one for you, have in mind that these methods should be implemented only if needed, according to the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Finally, the assignment operator should look like this:

```
Profile& operator=(const Profile &other) {
    this->name = other.name;
    this->age = other.age;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: "should be implemented only when needed" - this goes against the rule of 3, no?

Comment: @peer_2_peer_2 The rule of 3 is actually the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). It reads *"**If** a class requires a user-defined destructor, a user-defined copy constructor, or a user-defined copy assignment operator, it almost certainly requires all three."*. Ideally, design your classes such that the compiler provided constructors, destructor and assignement operators work well. Then don't implement any of them. That's the zero part of the rule.

Comment: From the content of the question, it doesn't look the OP would understand the implications of the rule but it makes sense to include it in the answer. Now I see that he is actually aware of the rule so I updated the answer with a link. Thanks for pointing that out.